# Architecture for plugins to be loaded in runtime

Tags: plugins, clojure, runtime

Considering that I am developing an end-user software program (as an uberjar) I am wondering what my options are to make it possible for the user to download a plugin and load that during runtime.

The plugin(s) should come compiled and without source code, so sth. like `load` is not an option.
What existing libraries (or ways of Java...?) exist to build this on?

**EDIT:** If you are not sure I would also be satisfied with a way that costs a reboot/-start of the main-program. However, what is important is that the source-code won't be included in any JAR file (neither main application nor plugin-jars, see :omit-source of Leiningen documentation).

Answer (score 5):

To add a jar during runtime, use [pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) which lets you add a .jar file to the classpath. Plugins of your software should be regular Clojure libs that follow certain conventions that you need to establish:

1. Make them provide (e. g. in an `edn`) a symbol to an object implementing a constructor/destructor mechanism such as the `Lifecycle` protocol in Stuart Sierras [component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) library. In runtime, `require` and `resolve` that symbol, `start` the resulting object and hand it over to rest your programs plugin coordination facilities.
2. Provide a public API in your program that allows the plugins to interact with it in ways that you coordinate asynchronously e. g. with `clojure.core.async` (don't let one plugin block the entire program).
3. Make sure that the plugins have a coordinated way to expose their functionality to each other only if they desire so to enable a high degree of modularity among your plugins. Make sure that your plugin loader is capable of detecting dependencies among plugins and is capable of loading and unloading them in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it myself, but you should in theory be able to get [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) to work with Clojure.

There's a Clojure / OSGi integration library here:

- https://github.com/aav/clojure.osgi

Comment: It seems like OSGi is the Java way to do it. The github repo is really poorly documented and seems highly hackish from a look at the source-code. If there is nothing comparable I am probably going to write a wrapper for OSGi myself.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to attempt to role my own solution, I would try using [tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace/) to load and unload plugins. I'm not entirely sure it will work, but it's certainly in the right direction. I think one key piece is that the plugin jars will have to be "installed" in a location that's already on the classpath.

Again, this is only the start of one possible solution. I haven't tried doing this.

Comment: Are you sure if tools.namespace.find works when the source-code is not included in the JARs?

Comment: I haven't tried, but the README states that tools.namespace.find contains "utilities to search for Clojure namespaces on the filesystem, in directories or JAR files. Combined with java.classpath, it can search for namespaces on the Java classpath."

Comment: Unfortunately it can not find any namespaces in JAR files without source :(